# Function to determine which polygon a coordinate is inside of is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, polygon

I need to find/use a function that takes an array of polygons and determines which polygons a coordinate is inside of. I was able to import the function in this github project: https://github.com/mikolalysenko/robust-point-in-polygon.

When I test the function using the exact same syntax as on the website, it works correctly (returns -1):

```
const test = [[-74, 50], [-80, 47], [-74, 45], [-70, 47]]
console.log(classifyPoint(test, [-73.5698065, 45.5031824]))
```

When I create an array of polygons and put the function inside of a loop (so that it goes through the list of polygons & compares it to the same coordinates), it works incorrectly (returns 1):

```
const zones = [
[[-104, 47], [-100, 47], [-100, 50], [-104, 45]],
[[-74, 50], [-80, 47], [-74, 45], [-70, 47]]
];

function findZone(long, lat) {
    for (i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {

    const zone = zones[i]
    
    let result = classifyPoint(zone, [long, lat])

    console.log(result)

        if (result === -1 && (i = 0)) {
            return "try again :("
        }
        if (result === -1 && (i = 1)) {
            return "YAHOO"
        }
        else {
            return "womp"
        }
    }
}


console.log(findZone(-73.5698065, 45.5031824))
```

I don't want to use the Google Maps API. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are accidentally assigning `i` instead of comparing it here:

```
        if (result === -1 && (i = 0)) {
            return "try again :("
        }
        if (result === -1 && (i = 1)) {
            return "YAHOO"
        }
```

Try changing `=` to `===` like this:

```
        if (result === -1 && (i === 0)) {
            return "try again :("
        }
        if (result === -1 && (i === 1)) {
            return "YAHOO"
        }
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, thanks!